# How does isatty() get the information from the terminal?

Tags: linux, bash

I noticed that if I type:

```
ls --color=auto
```

or

```
ls --color=auto | cat
ls --color=auto > >(cat)
```

I don't see the same output. Therefore I assume a program has an hability to know whether its STDOUT is piped to something. The question is how does it know?

I checked the ENV vars with `env` and `env | cat` but I get the same. The answer is somewhere else. I can't figure out where.

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564503/how-do-i-check-if-my-program-has-data-piped-into-it) I found that I can use `isatty()` who provide this function? is it part of the shell or the kernel? By going further I see that this function is part of the POSIX standard.

Now I know I have two processes that can communicate in between them with several mechanism:

- STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR
- Exit Code
- Environment variables
- System calls

Bash and ls are both programs. Thus they can only use the listed mechanisms to exchange information.

The real question behind this is how does `isatty()` get the information from bash?

Comment: @Steven - That's a completely different problem.

Comment: @AFH not really. With the answer given by Steven, I found that a program will use the POSIX function `isatty()`. I will need to modify my question into: Is `isatty()` a function linked to the shell or to the kernel?

Comment: @Steven Sorry I was confused and asked a X-Y problem...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `--color` option is a feature of the GNU `ls` program. GNU `ls` uses the [`isatty()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isatty.html) function to test whether the process's standard output is a TTY. Part of the relevant source code can be seen [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/ls.c;hb=b9842a615366b47cbd0739d97f2dd2679dfbb3a8#l1869):

```
    case COLOR_OPTION:
      {
        int i;
        if (optarg)
          i = XARGMATCH ("--color", optarg, color_args, color_types);
        else
          /* Using --color with no argument is equivalent to using
             --color=always.  */
          i = color_always;

        print_with_color = (i == color_always
                            || (i == color_if_tty
                                && isatty (STDOUT_FILENO)));
```

> The real question behind this is how does isatty() get the information from bash?

`isatty()` inspects the file descriptor passed to it to see if the file descriptor represents a TTY (terminal device). The exact way that isatty() works may vary from one system to another. Here is a [Darwin implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/isatty.c) from Apple OSX if you're interested:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
isatty(fd)
    int fd;
{
    struct termios t;

    return(tcgetattr(fd, &t) != -1);
}
```

When you run `ls --color=auto`, your shell (bash) launches the "ls" program using the shell's own standard input, output, and error as the stdin/out/err for the "ls" process. If you are running interactively, then your shell's stdout is probably a terminal, then ls's standard output will probably be a terminal. When ls calls isatty() to test whether its standard output is a terminal, it will probably succeed.

When you run something like `ls --color=auto | cat`, your shell does three things:

1. Create a pipe.
2. Launch `cat` with its standard input set to be the pipe.
3. Launch `ls` with its standard output set to be the pipe.

A pipe is not a terminal. When `ls` tests whether its standard output is a tty, the test will fail.